# how to get link from uploded file on server

Tags: php, jquery

I create uploader for my server and it is working fine. Now i want to, when file upload, show user link to that file. I create thi table where user can see filename, filesize, filetype in "upload" folder. now i want to this table to show direct link to this file. Here is my code for table ..

```
$myDirectory = opendir(".");

while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
    $dirArray[] = $entryName;
}

closedir($myDirectory);

$indexCount = count($dirArray);
Print ("$indexCount files<br>\n");

sort($dirArray);

print("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class=whitelinks>\n");
print("<TR><TH>Filename</TH><th>Filetype</th><th>Filesize</th><th>Link</th><th>Delete</th></TR>\n");

for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
        if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){
        print("<TR><TD><a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></td>");
        print("<td>");  print(filetype($dirArray[$index])); print("</td>");
        print("<td>");  print(filesize($dirArray[$index])); print("</td>");
        print("<td><a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">Link</a> </td>");
        print("<td>"); echo 'Delete'; print("</td>");
        print("</TR>\n");

    }
}
print("</TABLE>\n");

?>
```

Comment: A link for downloading the file, you mean?

Comment: Create a `php` file that includes a query parameter. Then you can process the download in the `php` file by using `$_GET['parameter']` to redirect to the file.

Answer (score 1):

After your files gets uploaded, from your backend PHP page (where your file upload code resides) you should return the all file attributes in a `json string` as `ajax response` and on the javascript page you can utilize those attributes to display file information and create a link to the uploaded file